# Laravel : count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to add this feature called booking for others. If the user want to order 5 tour package, user have to input 4 emails of that user friends, to notify them that they got the tour package by this user. The idea i had is to store the emails in array. When i tried to create the front-end i got error `count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given`. How can i store the array value??

The Controller :

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $numbers = $request->numbers;
        $emails = $request->email;
        for($count = 0; $count < count($numbers); $count++){
            emails::create([
                'email'=>$emails[$count]
            ]);
        }
        return redirect ('/home/');
    }
```

The blade file :

```
<form action="{{route('EmailStore')}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>How many people</label>
        <input type="text" required class="form-control @error ('numbers') is-invalid @enderror" 
        id="numbers" name="numbers" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    @php
        $emails = count($numbers);
    @endphp
    @for ($i = 0; $i < $emails; $i++)
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Email.{{$i}}</label>
                <input type="text" required class="form-control @error ('email') is-invalid @enderror" 
                id="email" name="email[]" autocomplete="off">
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endfor
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="btn_submit" 
        style="background-color: #eefa69; border:none; color:black">Submit</button>
</form>
```

For example input is like this :
`How many book : 5`

```
Email number 1 : a@gmail.com
Email number 2 : b@gmail.com
Email number 3: c@gmail.com
Email number 4: d@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$request->number` is an integer and a string specifying a number, you can use:

```
for ($count = 0; $count < intval($numbers); $count++) {
    .
    .
    .
```

If it's an array and to be sure:

```
for ($count = 0; $count < count((array) $numbers); $count++) {
    .
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 0):

It works better to associate the email table with the user table.

| id | user_id | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | friend1@email |
| 1 | 1 | friend2@email |
| 1 | 2 | friend3@email |

User model should have many to many relation with booking_emails table. After this, you can use attach() method. You don't need the loop you use to save emails. [attaching / detaching](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

Then you can report:

- How many people booking for friends,
- How many unique users have booked in total etc.

If you work with array, you can get this informations but its not gonna be better solution/performance.